# Object.assign to update the array element in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, assign

Here is the code:

```
    var state = {
    txn:[],
    do:false
}

var newState = Object.assign ({}, state, 
    {
        txn: state.txn.slice(0,0).concat([{txnId:3, b:5}, {txnId:5, b:6}])
    },
    {
        do: !state.do
    }
);

var newState2 = Object.assign ({}, newState, 
{
    txn[0].txnId: 9
});
```

The first `Object.assign` works and the `newState` has the `txn` array filled with two elements.

The second `Object.assign` is not working. 
It says that "[" is an unexpected token.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no  `txn`, it's a key in an object, not a variable, it has to be `newState.txn`

Comment: but it works in the first Object.assign.

Comment: No it doesn't, you don't use `txn` in the first one, you set a key with that name, and use `state.txn`, never just `txn`

Comment: In the first one I used "txn: ….." and this is what i have used it in the second one. Can you please send me the code that you are suggesting?

Comment: I'd do this -> https://jsfiddle.net/1b6zxgdm/

Comment: And note that `txn : ...` is setting a key, it's not the same as as `txn[0].txnId : ...` which is not correct syntax.

Comment: Should this newState.txn[0].txnId = 9; be "newState2.txn[0].txnId = 9;" in your code?

Comment: Yes, a small typo, to change `newState2` it has to of course be `newState2.txn...`

Comment: If  you would like to dynamically refer to the property of the last object to be assigned then you should probably do like `var newState2 = Object.assign ({}, newState, {[newState.txn[0].txnId]: 9});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved this way:

```
var newState2 = Object.assign ({}, newState, 
{
    txn: newState.txn.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === 0)  {
        return { txnId: item.txnId, b: 9 };
      }
      else {
        return item;
      }
    })
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJEoJd?editors=1111